# What could be causing my Chrome content script to not load despite correct syntax and attempts to fix?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

The only 2 files I have in my extension are the ones below, but `content.js` is not being loaded on any web page I try to access (it doesn't appear on the page's dev tools and won't change the page color to red either). Already tried adding different permissions, changing the pattern to a specific site and accessing it, uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting chrome, changing `run_at` to all possible values, checking `chrome://policy`, adding `debugger` statement to my code, but no luck. What could be causing this issue?

This is `manifest.json`

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "Debug",
  "short_name": "Debug",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is `content.js`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.style.color = "red";
});
```

Obs.: This is just a small extension I made to debug the problem of my main extension, turns both content scripts are not being loaded, I can see bitwarden's content script on the page's devtools though.

Comment: You don't need to use `DOMContentLoaded`. `content.js` isn't loaded until after the DOM is loaded. Try doing without that.

Comment: That is correct, I'm sorry for the confusion, content scripts are in another tab in devtools. Removing the event listener makes the font red and if I add a `debugger` statement it stops there when I reload the page. Unfortunately my main extension is being loaded but `debugger` statements have no effect and it is not working. I can't post its code here since it's proprietary code and it's outside the scope of this question since it is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts are shown in another tab in the sources tab, you have to click the right arrow and content scripts. Also the event listened in `DOMContentLoaded` is wrong since the script is only loaded after the document has loaded, removing it worked.

Edit: the issue was that I was trying to import code from other file.